# ShowMe command is not available in Word

Tags: c#, word-interop

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application ShowMe() method is giving this exception:

MESSAGE: The ShowMe command is not available in Word.
SOURCE: Microsoft Word
STACK:    at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass.ShowMe()

This has been working until recently. Might be Windows 11 but I cannot find anything anywhere about it.

Anyone had this issue?

Comment: **Exactly** what version of Word are you running? (Post the exact version number and info from File > Account, not the marketing-name, e.g. "Word 2019" or "Office 365 Word" which aren't very helpful).

Comment: Note the [caution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.showme)

Comment: Ah B***** missed that, thank you

Comment: I can't see in the documentation a method to replace it!

Comment: @AlexHall try Activate() instead.

Answer (score 1):

The same error came up for me when using the Word Merge feature in Microsoft Access which uses the ShowMe() function in word. This started beginning Friday 11/4/2022 for me. As of 11/8/2022, we have rolled back to a previous version of Office and this solved the problem.

The bad Microsoft Office 365 version I was running when I had the issue was "Version 2210 Build 16.0.15726.20070" from October 27th (see first link below). As far as I can tell, this is specific to the Current Channel only. Monthly and Semi-Annual Channels should be unaffected for a while still. Hopefully Microsoft fixes the issue before it reaches the other channels.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/current-channel#version-2210-october-27

Rolling back to "Version 2208 Build 16.0.15601.20204" resolved the issue for me (see link below for Sept 13th version).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/current-channel#version-2208-september-13

Microsoft Office 365 Versions are confusing as the last few digits can vary, so just roll back to 16.0.15601.20xxx at least and you should be good to go.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/33109459)

Comment: @mdaniel I applied the solution I had originally proposed. I was correct, as it has resolved my issue and will likely resolve other people's issues. If you can, please remove/modify your comment stating that my answer doesn't answer the question. My answer has now been updated with adequate detail. Let me know if you think I missed anything and I'll update it further as I am new here. Thank you